# Get number of items in a ReplaySubject with Array Element

Tags: swift, rx-swift, subject, replay

I have to use ReplaySubject in my project like that:

```
let myVariable = ReplaySubject<[MyItems]>.create(bufferSize: myBufferSize)
```

How can I get the number of items in the array of "MyItems"?

Answer (score -1):

Simply map the array to its count:

`let countObservable = myVariable.map { $0.count }`